# Snackbar with API 21

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-design-library, android-snackbar

I'm trying to implement the new Snackbars in my app but I can't. First of all I downloaded the zip file from [this SnackBarSampleActivity](https://github.com/nispok/snackbar/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/nispok/sample/snackbar/SnackbarSampleActivity.java).
I unziped it and then I import it in Eclipse. Now I get an error `retrieving parent...` for the theme parent in `styles.xml`.
I change it to `android:Theme.Light` and the error was gone. I right clicked the project and checked isLibrary in Properties/Android, I right clicked my app and in Properties/Android I add the library. Finally I paste the code to show a `Snackbar` but I get an error because `Snackbar cannot be resolved`.
Please somebody help me! I'm going crazy, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should try to use Android Studio, because the ADT plugin for Eclipse is no longer in active development.

In Android Studio, you just need to add a line `compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.6.1'` in your `build.gradle` dependencies, such that

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.6.1'
}
```

That's it.

Comment: I think I'll give it a try. In general is it similar to eclipse?

Comment: Sure it is, it better than eclipse, such as Auto-complete and Extract, and now is a official IDE

Comment: Have you tried? If it works, plz mark this answer as best, thx

Comment: Later today I'll try it and if it works I'll mark your answer, don't worry :)

Answer (score 40):

With the new [Design Support Library](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html) you can use the official [SnackBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html) Widget.

Just add this dependency to your `app -> build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

And use something like:

```
Snackbar.make(view, "Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

[image]

**Full Example, In Kotlin**

```
        val fab = findViewById(R.id.btn_signin) as Button
        fab.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "FloatingActionButton is clicked", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show()
        })
```

Comment: Does this apply to FloatingActionButton also?

Comment: It does http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html.

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes. it can work with the official FAB.

Answer (score 6):

If you are facing "not resolved to a type" issue in Eclipse for **Snackbar**, 
this worked for me.

Right click on Project->BuildPath->Configure Buildpath Click on Libraries Tab and then click on Add external Libraries.

Select {path of adt}/sdk/extras/android/support/design/libs Select android-support-design.jar, Click Open to add this library.

Click Ok.

[image: Final Window]

Answer (score 1):

Please add the below code to the **build.gradle** file

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

after that Click the  Sync Now button,It will work.

Comment: can you please explain more about  what you have done?

Answer (score 0):

**For Eclipse Developers**

1. Follow the instructions given in github to import SnackBar project
2. Right click on the **java** folder and click `build path > add as source folder`
3. add these lines/change SnackBar project's `AndroidManifest.xml` as follows

   ```
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
       android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>
   <application />
   ```

> package="com.nispok.snackbar"

4. Add following `dependencies` to the SnackBar project

> android-support-v7-appcompat: 21 
>   android-support-v7-recyclerview: 21

5. Finally set Project build target to API 22 in project properties.

That's it will be working for you, Have a great coding day..

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your build.gradle (Module: app) inside dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

or

```
implementation 'com.dmitrymalkovich.android:material-design-dimens:1.4'
```

Complete code:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

or

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.dmitrymalkovich.android:material-design-dimens:1.4'
}
```