# Cannot add dependency to "android.support.design.widget.Snackbar" with gradle in Android studio when add new Login activity

Tags: android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin, android-snackbar, dependency-resolver

I am trying to add an Login activity from Android studio, using New->Activity->Login.
The code contain "import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;". I tried to build it and got "Cannot resolve symbol'Snackbar'". I added Snackbar to app->build.gradle like below (*compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.6.1'*), follow [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488826/snackbar-with-api-21):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ndhy.flashcom"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
    compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:+'
}
```

Then I tried to "Sync project with gradle files", but the problem still hasn't be resolved. Stackbar support still be not imported.
How could I fix that?
Is Snackbar depend on some version of appcompat?

Comment: add, compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'